# Point pattern analysis suggestions - at risk habitats

Tags: forest-ecology, habitat-modeling, wildlife-ecology, environmental-monitoring

I have two point datasets across a state.

1. Locations that have sensitive vegetation and locations of threatened wildlife
2. Recorded locations of damage / degradation occurrences

The data as you'd expect is predominantly clustered in some way (e.g national parks near built up areas).
Let's say the first dataset of species/vegetation was weighted by its vulnerability, and the second, damage/wrongdoing, was weighted also by its type (e.g. shooting bird, clearing, etc). How would i compare these to highlight the areas of most importance?